Trying to have my dropdown menu open directly under the div
I have a menu with one dropdown item. However, I can't make it work so it open under the associated div item.
Here's my code :


.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    float: right;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.top-menu a{
    color: black;
    float: right;
    right:0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 24px 26px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}

.col-12 {width: 100%; align-items:normal;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="col-12">
<header>
<div class="top-menu" id="myTopnav">
<div><a href="#">Item 3</a></div>
<div><a href="#" target="_blank">Item 2</a></div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <a>Item 1 (dropdown)</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <div><a>1</a></div>
<div><a>2</a></div>
<div><a>3</a></div>
<div><a>4</a></div>
<div><a>5</a></div>
  
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
</div>

</body>
</html>



Ideally, the dropdown-content would open directly under Item 1 (dropdown) wherever this item is located (e.g. if Item 1 was to be located on the far right side).
Thanks in advance for your replies !

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  float: right;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;

  width: 100%;
}


thx ! however it should be vertically align.

This issue is actually with how you laid out the navigation bar. Instead of floating the links to the right, you should display the entire nav bar using display: flex.
THen you can do:
.dropdown:hover {
    position: relative;
    .dropdown-content {
       display: block;
    }
}

to position the parent element ONLY on hover. You don't want it to always create it's own stacking context. You only want that on hover. And, yes, nesting is now native in browsers, it doesn't require Sass.
then you can use inset properties like top / left or inset-block-start and inset-inline-start to position your drop-down.
Pretty soon you'll be able to use CSS anchor positioning, but that's only in chromium for right now, but should be part of baseline 2024
